# Android AVD only allowing multiples of 1GB RAM

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I was setting the value for RAM size in AVD itself in Android Studio, trying values of 512mb, 768mb, and 1536mb, none of the above values were working, with the system itself registering 1024mb RAM. However, setting it to 2048MB works. The same behaviour also applies when running the emulator in the SDK itself from the command line using the -memory argument.

Above behaviour is occuring with the API 25 x86_64 image.